# Let $F:A \to A$ be a function and let $Y \subseteq A$. Prove that the class $S = \{B:Y\subseteq B \subseteq A$ and $F[B] \subseteq B\}$ is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Let $F:A \to A$ be a function and let $Y \subseteq A$.

(a) Prove that the class $S = \{B:Y\subseteq B \subseteq A$ and $F[B] \subseteq B\}$ is a set.

Can I use the theorem that states: Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula.  Suppose that there is a set $A$ such that for all $x$, if $\phi(x)$, then $x \in A$.  Then there is a unique set $D$ such that for all $x$, $x \in D$ iff $\phi(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: replace the letter $A$ in your theorem with $U$, so that it reads

> Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula.  Suppose that there is a set $U$ such that for all $x$, if $\phi(x)$, then $x \in U$.  Then there is a unique set $D$ such that for all $x$, $x \in D$ iff $\phi(x)$.

Rephrasing, that says that if you have some condition $\phi$ with the property that anything for which $\phi(x)$ is true is also in the set $U$ (but $U$ might have lots of other stuff in it), then you can also form the subset of $U$ consisting of things $x$ for which $\phi(x)$ is true.

The set you're trying to construct (the class named $S$) consists of a bunch of items generically named $B$. What kind of item is such a $B$?

Comment: I see that $B \subseteq A$ and hence, by the subset axiom, must itself be a set, so long as $A$ is a set, no?  I'm not sure what you mean when you say what kind of item is $B$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. So every $B$ is a subset of $A$ (although not every subset of $A$ is a suitable $B$, in general). So what might be a good choice for the set $U$, a set that contains everything that could possibly be one of the $B$s?

Comment: So I could just $\mathcal{P}(A)$, right?

Comment: Indeed, choosing $U$ to be the powerset of $A$ and applying that theorem should do the job (assuming you know that the powerset of $A$ is a set, which I assume is proven through some other mechanism).

Comment: But this shows that every $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, no?  So then $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: I guess I'd say that every $x$ for which $\phi(x)$ is true lies in $P(A)$, which is a set; therefore (by the theorem) the class $S$ is also a set.